# AWS Lambda function not triggered immediately from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS Lambda function with a timeout of 3 minutes and an SQS queue with a visibility timeout of 3 minutes. Maybe I don't understand something here, but why do my messages only trigger a lambda every 3 minutes?

I have concurrency configured for up to 10 lambdas at a time, so from my understanding I should be able to execute multiple lambdas at the same time. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are your Lambda functions regularly hitting the 3-minute timeout? Does the Lambda function sometimes return an error, indicating that the messages were not processed? Please edit your question and show us your code so we can see how you are receiving the messages -- people sometimes incorrectly write Lambda functions that directly call SQS, so I'd like to rule-out this possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note this recommendation from [Using Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html):

> To allow your function time to process each batch of records, set the source queue's visibility timeout to **at least six times the timeout that you configure on your function**. The extra time allows for Lambda to retry if your function is throttled while processing a previous batch.

Since your Lambda function is configured with a 3-minute timeout, the recommendation would be to set the SQS queue visibility timeout to **18 minutes**.

The fact that your "messages only trigger a lambda every 3 minutes" suggests to that the Lambda function is not correctly indicating that a message was processed. This then causes the message to be re-processed, but only after the SQS invisibility timeout is met.

The vast majority of your messages should be successfully processed without hitting any errors or timeouts. If this is not the case, then examine CloudWatch Logs to determine whether/why messages are failing to process.